# Can given function be properly defined in order to be continous at origin? Is my attempt correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$P1 : \sin(x/y)$  .

I tried using $y=mx$. $f$ becomes $\sin(1/m)$, so limit doesn't exist. But it is too easy. Am I right?

$P2 : F = x^2\log(x^2+y^2)$

[image]

[image: Attempt]

So function can be defined as O at origin in order to be continous . Am I right in these? Im learning this stuff on my own.

Comment: Pictures are mostly unreadable. $f$ becomes $\sin \left( {1/m} \right)$, not $sin\left( {\sin \left( {1/m} \right)} \right)$, but your conclusion is correct

Comment: @Alen sorry i dont know how to type in this language  site demands . so i put pictures which i find less tedious

Comment: I didn't mean the handwriting, which is nice from what I can tell. The pictures themselves are all red or cyan, except for the small part (beginning and middle)

Comment: @Alen I will take care in future

Comment: Here it is explained how to type maths text here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $\left( {x,y} \right) = \left( {r\sin \phi ,y = r\cos \phi } \right) = \varphi \left( {r,\phi } \right)$ gives $f\left( {x,y} \right) = f\left( {\varphi \left( {r,\phi } \right)} \right) = {\sin ^2}\left( \phi  \right){r^2}\ln {r^2}$.

If the limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to 0} {\sin ^2}\left( \phi  \right){r^2}\ln {r^2}$ exists, so does the limit in question exist. We have $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to 0} {\sin ^2}\left( \phi  \right){r^2}\ln {r^2} = 0$, which answers the quesiton.

Answer (score 2):

P1 is easy indeed and you are correct.

In P2 the limit is 0, but your attempt shows only limits on lines $y=mx$. A correct version is similar to that from answers to your previous question:
$$
|x^2\log(x^2+y^2)|\leq|(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)|.
$$
But you should know, that 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln{x}=0,
$$
and this ends the proof.

Comment: Much thanks !!!